# Firebase doesn't let me log in again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j34Hn.png)

I have implemented firebase log in and password method correctly in my react application (For Website). It works first time when I try to login. After logout from the webpage, if I try to log in again. It shows me this error. What is the solution for this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share your code that is not working as intended? Also try logging the email right before `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` function just to ensure the value is defined.

Comment: Did you enable authentication in the firebase console https://imgur.com/FqJf2cb

Also check in the authentication -> users area if the user is listed there